# How to create a Folium Map

Tags: python, maps, folium

I want to create an interactive map using folium. something like this Covid19 map, but I want to use median rental price data in nyc.

[image]

here is data I want to use (median rent nyc)

[image]

so far I have these code, but it generates errors, and I do not know how to proceed with this. Any help would be appreciated !

```
    df = pd.read_csv("Median-rent_estimate.csv")
    df.head() 
    #creating the Choropleth map (import geojson file)
    Ny_map = 'Median_rent.geojson'
    import folium
    latitude = 40.730610
    longitude = -73.935242

    Ny_map = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude], zoom_start= 12)

    #generating choropleth map 
    Ny_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=Ny_map,
    data=result,
    columns=['Zipcode', 'Median Rent'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Median rental price in NY'
    )

    # display map
    Ny_map
```

Thank you

```
geojson: 
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Median_rent_estimate_NYC_2",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Chelsea and Clinton", "Zipcode": "10001", "Latitude": 40.750742, "Longitude": -73.99653, "Median Rent": "3097.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99653, 40.750742 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Lower East Side", "Zipcode": "10003", "Latitude": 40.732509, "Longitude": -73.98935, "Median Rent": "3447" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.98935, 40.732509 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Lower Manhattan", "Zipcode": "10004", "Latitude": 40.699, "Longitude": -74.041, "Median Rent": "4852.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.041, 40.699 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Lower Manhattan", "Zipcode": "10005", "Latitude": 40.706019, "Longitude": -74.00858, "Median Rent": "4839" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.00858, 40.706019 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Gramercy Park and Murray Hill", "Zipcode": "10010", "Latitude": 40.739022, "Longitude": -73.98205, "Median Rent": "3885" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.98205, 40.739022 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Chelsea and Clinton", "Zipcode": "10011", "Latitude": 40.741012, "Longitude": -74.00012, "Median Rent": "3172.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.00012, 40.741012 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Greenwich Village and Soho", "Zipcode": "10012", "Latitude": 40.72596, "Longitude": -73.99834, "Median Rent": "3420" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99834, 40.72596 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Greenwich Village and Soho", "Zipcode": "10013", "Latitude": 40.720666, "Longitude": -74.00526, "Median Rent": "2356.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.00526, 40.720666 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Gramercy Park and Murray Hill", "Zipcode": "10016", "Latitude": 40.74618, "Longitude": -73.97759, "Median Rent": "3825" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.97759, 40.74618 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Upper East Side", "Zipcode": "10021", "Latitude": 40.76842, "Longitude": -73.96045, "Median Rent": "3223.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.96045, 40.76842 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Upper West Side", "Zipcode": "10023", "Latitude": 40.776099, "Longitude": -73.98285, "Median Rent": "3481.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.98285, 40.776099 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Upper West Side", "Zipcode": "10024", "Latitude": 40.786387, "Longitude": -73.97709, "Median Rent": "3261" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.97709, 40.786387 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Harlem", "Zipcode": "10026", "Latitude": 40.802853, "Longitude": -73.95471, "Median Rent": "1744.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.95471, 40.802853 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Harlem", "Zipcode": "10027", "Latitude": 40.812665, "Longitude": -73.95499, "Median Rent": "1789.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.95499, 40.812665 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Upper East Side", "Zipcode": "10028", "Latitude": 40.776777, "Longitude": -73.9541, "Median Rent": "3493.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.9541, 40.776777 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "East Harlem", "Zipcode": "10029", "Latitude": 40.791586, "Longitude": -73.94575, "Median Rent": "1384.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94575, 40.791586 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Inwood and Washington Heights", "Zipcode": "10031", "Latitude": 40.826201, "Longitude": -73.94879, "Median Rent": "2047.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94879, 40.826201 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Inwood and Washington Heights", "Zipcode": "10032", "Latitude": 40.840686, "Longitude": -73.94154, "Median Rent": "1828.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94154, 40.840686 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "East Harlem", "Zipcode": "10035", "Latitude": 40.802395, "Longitude": -73.93359, "Median Rent": "1299" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.93359, 40.802395 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Chelsea and Clinton", "Zipcode": "10036", "Latitude": 40.759511, "Longitude": -73.99019, "Median Rent": "3226.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99019, 40.759511 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Upper East Side", "Zipcode": "10128", "Latitude": 40.781894, "Longitude": -73.95039, "Median Rent": "3297" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.95039, 40.781894 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Lower Manhattan", "Zipcode": "10280", "Latitude": 40.707467, "Longitude": -74.0178, "Median Rent": "4998" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.0178, 40.707467 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Stapleton and St. George", "Zipcode": "10301", "Latitude": 40.631775, "Longitude": -74.09432, "Median Rent": "1936.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.09432, 40.631775 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Port Richmond", "Zipcode": "10302", "Latitude": 40.631127, "Longitude": -74.13715, "Median Rent": "1987.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.13715, 40.631127 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Port Richmond", "Zipcode": "10303", "Latitude": 40.629448, "Longitude": -74.16239, "Median Rent": "1513.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.16239, 40.629448 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Stapleton and St. George", "Zipcode": "10304", "Latitude": 40.60787, "Longitude": -74.08991, "Median Rent": "1551" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.08991, 40.60787 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "South Shore", "Zipcode": "10306", "Latitude": 40.569394, "Longitude": -74.11785, "Median Rent": "2041.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.11785, 40.569394 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "South Shore", "Zipcode": "10307", "Latitude": 40.508274, "Longitude": -74.24387, "Median Rent": "1797" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.24387, 40.508274 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "South Shore", "Zipcode": "10309", "Latitude": 40.529749, "Longitude": -74.21304, "Median Rent": "2083.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.21304, 40.529749 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "South Shore", "Zipcode": "10312", "Latitude": 40.543117, "Longitude": -74.17628, "Median Rent": "1857" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.17628, 40.543117 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Mid-Island", "Zipcode": "10314", "Latitude": 40.606337, "Longitude": -74.14513, "Median Rent": "2101.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.14513, 40.606337 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "High Bridge and Morrisania", "Zipcode": "10451", "Latitude": 40.819729, "Longitude": -73.9223, "Median Rent": "1563" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.9223, 40.819729 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "High Bridge and Morrisania", "Zipcode": "10452", "Latitude": 40.838745, "Longitude": -73.92234, "Median Rent": "1708.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.92234, 40.838745 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Bronx", "Zipcode": "10453", "Latitude": 40.853017, "Longitude": -73.91214, "Median Rent": "1695" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.91214, 40.853017 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Hunts Point and Mott Haven", "Zipcode": "10454", "Latitude": 40.805968, "Longitude": -73.91628, "Median Rent": "1095" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.91628, 40.805968 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Hunts Point and Mott Haven", "Zipcode": "10455", "Latitude": 40.815559, "Longitude": -73.90771, "Median Rent": "1461" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90771, 40.815559 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "High Bridge and Morrisania", "Zipcode": "10456", "Latitude": 40.829676, "Longitude": -73.90856, "Median Rent": "1528.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90856, 40.829676 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Bronx", "Zipcode": "10457", "Latitude": 40.846745, "Longitude": -73.89861, "Median Rent": "1731" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.89861, 40.846745 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Bronx Park and Fordham", "Zipcode": "10458", "Latitude": 40.864166, "Longitude": -73.88881, "Median Rent": "1833" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.88881, 40.864166 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Hunts Point and Mott Haven", "Zipcode": "10459", "Latitude": 40.825432, "Longitude": -73.89327, "Median Rent": "1530" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.89327, 40.825432 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Bronx", "Zipcode": "10460", "Latitude": 40.84095, "Longitude": -73.88036, "Median Rent": "1579.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.88036, 40.84095 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10461", "Latitude": 40.842917, "Longitude": -73.83819, "Median Rent": "2059.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.83819, 40.842917 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10462", "Latitude": 40.842173, "Longitude": -73.85862, "Median Rent": "2013" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.85862, 40.842173 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Kingsbridge and Riverdale", "Zipcode": "10463", "Latitude": 40.881086, "Longitude": -73.90749, "Median Rent": "1989" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90749, 40.881086 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10466", "Latitude": 40.89095, "Longitude": -73.84702, "Median Rent": "1921.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.84702, 40.89095 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Bronx Park and Fordham", "Zipcode": "10467", "Latitude": 40.872265, "Longitude": -73.86937, "Median Rent": "1927.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.86937, 40.872265 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Bronx Park and Fordham", "Zipcode": "10468", "Latitude": 40.867107, "Longitude": -73.89916, "Median Rent": "1854" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.89916, 40.867107 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10469", "Latitude": 40.868643, "Longitude": -73.84735, "Median Rent": "2068.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.84735, 40.868643 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Kingsbridge and Riverdale", "Zipcode": "10471", "Latitude": 40.900819, "Longitude": -73.90347, "Median Rent": "2322" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90347, 40.900819 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10472", "Latitude": 40.830409, "Longitude": -73.86845, "Median Rent": "1759.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.86845, 40.830409 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Bronx", "Zipcode": "10473", "Latitude": 40.818514, "Longitude": -73.85893, "Median Rent": "1446" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.85893, 40.818514 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Hunts Point and Mott Haven", "Zipcode": "10474", "Latitude": 40.81321, "Longitude": -73.88755, "Median Rent": "1707" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.88755, 40.81321 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11004", "Latitude": 40.742944, "Longitude": -73.70956, "Median Rent": "2238" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.70956, 40.742944 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11101", "Latitude": 40.745341, "Longitude": -73.93907, "Median Rent": "2412" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.93907, 40.745341 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11102", "Latitude": 40.771286, "Longitude": -73.92462, "Median Rent": "2545.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.92462, 40.771286 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11106", "Latitude": 40.762012, "Longitude": -73.93147, "Median Rent": "2421" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.93147, 40.762012 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northwest Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11201", "Latitude": 40.695286, "Longitude": -73.98907, "Median Rent": "3615" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.98907, 40.695286 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Flatbush", "Zipcode": "11203", "Latitude": 40.649059, "Longitude": -73.93304, "Median Rent": "1959" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.93304, 40.649059 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Borough Park", "Zipcode": "11204", "Latitude": 40.618944, "Longitude": -73.98473, "Median Rent": "2062.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.98473, 40.618944 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northwest Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11205", "Latitude": 40.694214, "Longitude": -73.96529, "Median Rent": "2130" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.96529, 40.694214 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Bushwick and Williamsburg", "Zipcode": "11206", "Latitude": 40.702348, "Longitude": -73.94288, "Median Rent": "1602" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94288, 40.702348 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "East New York and New Lots", "Zipcode": "11207", "Latitude": 40.670874, "Longitude": -73.89424, "Median Rent": "1767" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.89424, 40.670874 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "East New York and New Lots", "Zipcode": "11208", "Latitude": 40.672666, "Longitude": -73.87248, "Median Rent": "1890" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.87248, 40.672666 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11209", "Latitude": 40.62327, "Longitude": -74.0295, "Median Rent": "2265" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.0295, 40.62327 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Flatbush", "Zipcode": "11210", "Latitude": 40.627946, "Longitude": -73.94552, "Median Rent": "2029.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94552, 40.627946 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Greenpoint", "Zipcode": "11211", "Latitude": 40.71209, "Longitude": -73.95427, "Median Rent": "2683.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.95427, 40.71209 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11212", "Latitude": 40.662191, "Longitude": -73.91328, "Median Rent": "1429.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.91328, 40.662191 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11213", "Latitude": 40.670937, "Longitude": -73.93459, "Median Rent": "1854" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.93459, 40.670937 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11214", "Latitude": 40.598994, "Longitude": -73.99611, "Median Rent": "2040" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99611, 40.598994 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Borough Park", "Zipcode": "11218", "Latitude": 40.644552, "Longitude": -73.97595, "Median Rent": "2325" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.97595, 40.644552 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Sunset Park", "Zipcode": "11220", "Latitude": 40.641436, "Longitude": -74.01574, "Median Rent": "2032.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.01574, 40.641436 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Bushwick and Williamsburg", "Zipcode": "11221", "Latitude": 40.691234, "Longitude": -73.92637, "Median Rent": "2058" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.92637, 40.691234 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Greenpoint", "Zipcode": "11222", "Latitude": 40.726302, "Longitude": -73.94559, "Median Rent": "2949" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.94559, 40.726302 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southern Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11223", "Latitude": 40.598142, "Longitude": -73.97229, "Median Rent": "1977" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.97229, 40.598142 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southern Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11224", "Latitude": 40.576589, "Longitude": -73.99172, "Median Rent": "1233" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.99172, 40.576589 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Sunset Park", "Zipcode": "11232", "Latitude": 40.655481, "Longitude": -74.00424, "Median Rent": "2238" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.00424, 40.655481 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Canarsie and Flatlands", "Zipcode": "11234", "Latitude": 40.618561, "Longitude": -73.9216, "Median Rent": "2172" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.9216, 40.618561 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Canarsie and Flatlands", "Zipcode": "11236", "Latitude": 40.640527, "Longitude": -73.90362, "Median Rent": "2065.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90362, 40.640527 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Brooklyn", "Zipcode": "11238", "Latitude": 40.680145, "Longitude": -73.96257, "Median Rent": "2595" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.96257, 40.680145 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "North Queens", "Zipcode": "11354", "Latitude": 40.767969, "Longitude": -73.82496, "Median Rent": "2160" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.82496, 40.767969 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "North Queens", "Zipcode": "11355", "Latitude": 40.749463, "Longitude": -73.81941, "Median Rent": "2088" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.81941, 40.749463 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "North Queens", "Zipcode": "11360", "Latitude": 40.780386, "Longitude": -73.78005, "Median Rent": "3070.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.78005, 40.780386 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11361", "Latitude": 40.763177, "Longitude": -73.77392, "Median Rent": "2674.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.77392, 40.763177 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Northeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11362", "Latitude": 40.759686, "Longitude": -73.73322, "Median Rent": "2712" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.73322, 40.759686 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Queens", "Zipcode": "11365", "Latitude": 40.738983, "Longitude": -73.79209, "Median Rent": "2335.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.79209, 40.738983 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Central Queens", "Zipcode": "11366", "Latitude": 40.726137, "Longitude": -73.79502, "Median Rent": "2619" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.79502, 40.726137 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Queens", "Zipcode": "11368", "Latitude": 40.747106, "Longitude": -73.85838, "Median Rent": "2358" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.85838, 40.747106 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Queens", "Zipcode": "11369", "Latitude": 40.762854, "Longitude": -73.87051, "Median Rent": "2254.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.87051, 40.762854 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Central Queens", "Zipcode": "11374", "Latitude": 40.724945, "Longitude": -73.8609, "Median Rent": "2386.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.8609, 40.724945 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Central Queens", "Zipcode": "11375", "Latitude": 40.720535, "Longitude": -73.84582, "Median Rent": "2596.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.84582, 40.720535 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Queens", "Zipcode": "11377", "Latitude": 40.742869, "Longitude": -73.90377, "Median Rent": "2235" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90377, 40.742869 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "West Queens", "Zipcode": "11378", "Latitude": 40.724096, "Longitude": -73.90271, "Median Rent": "2400" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.90271, 40.724096 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Jamaica", "Zipcode": "11412", "Latitude": 40.697188, "Longitude": -73.75948, "Median Rent": "2161.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.75948, 40.697188 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11414", "Latitude": 40.658188, "Longitude": -73.84321, "Median Rent": "2364" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.84321, 40.658188 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11415", "Latitude": 40.706903, "Longitude": -73.82973, "Median Rent": "2310" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.82973, 40.706903 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11419", "Latitude": 40.688688, "Longitude": -73.82216, "Median Rent": "2331" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.82216, 40.688688 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11420", "Latitude": 40.673138, "Longitude": -73.81443, "Median Rent": "2329.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.81443, 40.673138 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southwest Queens", "Zipcode": "11421", "Latitude": 40.69087, "Longitude": -73.85828, "Median Rent": "2418" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.85828, 40.69087 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Jamaica", "Zipcode": "11423", "Latitude": 40.714261, "Longitude": -73.76824, "Median Rent": "2116.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.76824, 40.714261 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11426", "Latitude": 40.732239, "Longitude": -73.72108, "Median Rent": "2593.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.72108, 40.732239 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11427", "Latitude": 40.728235, "Longitude": -73.74782, "Median Rent": "2098.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.74782, 40.728235 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11428", "Latitude": 40.719981, "Longitude": -73.74127, "Median Rent": "2230.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.74127, 40.719981 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Southeast Queens", "Zipcode": "11429", "Latitude": 40.708833, "Longitude": -73.73903, "Median Rent": "2101.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.73903, 40.708833 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Jamaica", "Zipcode": "11435", "Latitude": 40.700068, "Longitude": -73.80986, "Median Rent": "2199" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.80986, 40.700068 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Jamaica", "Zipcode": "11436", "Latitude": 40.674146, "Longitude": -73.79687, "Median Rent": "2386.5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.79687, 40.674146 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Rockaways", "Zipcode": "11691", "Latitude": 40.60002, "Longitude": -73.75962, "Median Rent": "1800" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.75962, 40.60002 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Rockaways", "Zipcode": "11692", "Latitude": 40.592939, "Longitude": -73.79568, "Median Rent": "1515" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.79568, 40.592939 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "State": "Roosevelt Island ", "Zipcode": "10044", "Latitude": 40.762, "Longitude": -73.949, "Median Rent": "3421" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.949, 40.762 ] } }
]
}
```

csv file:
[image]

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: I doesnt allow me to upload the whole data, I just uploaded a screenshot. Let me know it is sufficient

Comment: You should provide an excerpt (at least) of both the csv and the geojson file in a reusable format. Thanks.

Comment: ok, see if you can use it

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a choropleth map your geojson should have data with "geometry" of "type" "Polygon" or "MultiPolygon", and a list of coordinates for each district. What you provided does not meet these requirements.